# Как в linkedhashmap удалить елемент по value ( значению )

Tags: java, java-8

Всем привет, буду краток, у меня есть linkedhashmap и мне нужно удалить элемент по значения ( value ), проблема в том что если я напишу ( то что закоментировано в коде ) бросается ошибка ConcurrentModificationException, как это обойти? Код:

```
Map<Integer,String> linkedHashMapArray= new LinkedHashMap<>();
System.out.println("Generating.....");

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // randomNumber =20+ (int) ( Math.random() * 80 );

    keyInarraySet =20+ (int) ( Math.random() * 20 );
    valueInarraySet =1+ (int) ( Math.random() * 10 );

    map.put(keyInarraySet,valueInarraySet);

}
System.out.println("\nCompleted!");


System.out.println("Your Map");
System.out.println(map);

if (map.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("LinkedHashmap is empty, please input data");
    break;
}
System.out.println("Write  value which u want to delete");


System.out.println("Value: ");
valueInarraySet= cin.nextInt();



/*


for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry: map.entrySet()) {
    if(valueInarraySet == entry.getValue()){
        System.out.println(entry+" Ent  ");
        System.out.println("Now will be removed an"+entry.getValue()+" "+entry.getKey());
        findValueKey = entry.getKey();
        System.out.println(findValueKey+"  key  ");
        map.remove(findValueKey);

    }
}


*/


System.out.println("Your Map");
System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: Можно, например, создать колекцию ключей и писать туда ключи на удаление, а после пройтись по этой коллекции и удалить все соответствующие ключи из хешмапы.

Comment: Пользуйтесь поиском пожалуйста - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335935/whats-the-quickest-way-to-remove-an-element-from-a-map-by-value-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну во-первых, я бы попросил в следующий раз выкладывать такой код, который целиком можно скопировать куда-то себе и откомпилировать, чтобы не приходилось додумывать, что такое `keyInarraySet`, `valueInarraySet`, `map` и т.п. Эти переменные у вас в приведенном коде не описаны, а поведение кода зависит от того, как они определены. И желательно удалять из кода те части, которые не имеют отношения к проблеме, как например `Map<Integer,String> linkedHashMapArray` и ненужные сообщения в вашем коде.

Что касается удаления элемента из коллекции, то никакая коллекция не позволяет удалять элемент внутри такого цикла, где для управления циклом используются свойства самой этой коллекции, такие как `entrySet()` или `keys()`, и неважно, какого типа у вас коллекция -- `LinkedHashMap` или простой `HashMap`.

Даже с простым `ArrayList`, если вы напишете что-то типа

```
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(i) == 5)
      list.remove(i);
  }
```

то это не будет работать.

Дело в том, что при удалении элемента из коллекции сама коллекция меняется, и значит, условие цикла, которое основывалось на каких-то свойствах этой коллекции, после удаления будет уже неверно. В большинстве случаев вы получите исключение, как в вашем случае, но иногда программа просто будет неправильно работать, в зависимости от того, какой тип коллекции вы используете и как именно вы с ним обращаетесь. См. более подробное описание ситуации [на английском](https://www.java67.com/2018/12/how-to-remove-objects-or-elements-while-iterating-Arraylist-java.html)

Решить вашу задачу можно несколькими способами:

1. В цикле только найти тот элемент, который нужно удалить, а удалять его уже после выхода из цикла. Для этого внутри цикла надо запомнить ссылку на этот элемент, или его ключ, или еще что-то. Напр. так:

   ```
    private static void removeValueFromMap1(Map<Integer, Integer> map, int soughtValue) {
      System.out.println("Value to delete: " + soughtValue);

      Entry<Integer, Integer> found = null;
      for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry: map.entrySet()) {
        if(soughtValue == entry.getValue()) {
          found = entry;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (found == null)
        System.out.println("An entry with value " + soughtValue + " not found.");
      else {
        System.out.println("Removing entry " + found);
        map.remove(found.getKey());
      }
    }
   ```
2. Использовать итератор. Его метод `remove()` можно использовать прямо внутри цикла. Напр. так:

   ```
    private static void removeValueFromMap2(Map<Integer, Integer> map, int soughtValue) {
      System.out.println("Value to delete: " + soughtValue);

      Iterator<Entry<Integer, Integer>> i = map.entrySet().iterator();
      while (i.hasNext()) {
        Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = i.next();
        if(soughtValue == entry.getValue()) {
          System.out.println("Removing entry " + entry);
          i.remove();
          i = null; // Чтобы после выхода знать, что нашли и удалили
          break;
        }
      }

      if (i != null) // Это значит, что не нашли 
        System.out.println("An entry with value " + soughtValue + " not found.");
    }
   ```
3. Вообще не использовать поиск в цикле, а просто удалить нужное значение из коллекции значений, напр. так:

   ```
    private static void removeValueFromMap3(Map<Integer, Integer> map, int soughtValue) {
      System.out.println("Value to delete: " + soughtValue);

      if (map.values().contains(soughtValue)) {
        System.out.println("Removing value " + soughtValue);
        map.values().remove(soughtValue);
      } else {
        System.out.println("An entry with value " + soughtValue + " not found.");
      }
    }
   ```